# Save From buffered reader to JTextArea

Tags: java

I want to make the result of my buffered reader to appear in a text area, but It doesn't work for me.

I want the text area to get the result exactly as the system out print do, it is for more than one line, I tried to set the text area with string s but didn't work, just give me the result of one line.

Here is my Code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

import java.awt.ScrollPane;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;


public class Window extends JFrame {

/**
 * Launch the application.
 * @throws FileNotFoundException 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Window frame = new Window();
    frame.setTitle("SWMA Extractor");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setBounds(50, 50, 665, 550);
    //frame.setLocation(500, 300);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public Window() {
    setResizable(false);

    JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JLabel path = new JLabel("File Location");
    path.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    path.setBounds(20, 11, 74, 23);
    contentPane.add(path);

    final JTextField location = new JTextField();
    location.setBounds(104, 12, 306, 20);
    contentPane.add(location);
    location.setColumns(10);

    final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();

    ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setBounds(20, 80, 605, 430);
    contentPane.add(scrollPane);
    scrollPane.add(textArea);


    JButton btn = new JButton("Get Info.");
    btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
            chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
            File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
            File output = null;
            try {
                FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
                String s;
                int lineNumber = 1;
                while((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    if (s.contains("System")) {
                        System.out.println(s);
                        String nextLine = br.readLine();
                        System.out.println(nextLine);
                        String nextLine1 = br.readLine();
                        System.out.println(nextLine1);
                        String nextLine2 = br.readLine();
                        System.out.println(nextLine2);
                        String nextLine3 = br.readLine();
                        System.out.println(nextLine3);
                        System.out.println();

                    }
               }
                lineNumber++; 

            } catch (IOException e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
        } 
    });
    btn.setBounds(433, 11, 192, 23);
    contentPane.add(btn);

    JButton clr = new JButton("Clear");
    clr.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String getLocation = location.getText();
            String s;
            try {
                textArea.setText("");
                location.setText("");
            } catch (Exception e1) {

            }
        }
    });
    clr.setBounds(20, 45, 605, 23);
    contentPane.add(clr);
}
```

}

Comment: First problem -> `frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);`, also take a look at `JTextArea#read`. Why are you writing to `f` while you're trying to read from it?

Comment: You should check `!= null` everytime you call `br.readLine()`.

Comment: @MadProgrammer
It was by Mistake :)

Comment: @slartidan
it is there already in the while loop :)
while((s = br.readLine()) != null)

Comment: Three ways of doing this. Read each line, one at a time and append to your text area. Or just read every line to the end of the file, then append to your text area. OR read every line from the file. Then use a StringBuilder to construct the full contents of the TextArea and set the TextArea's content from the toString() method of the StringBuilder object.

Comment: @AboelmagdSaad I think you accidentally changed the accepted answer. Can you please check?

Comment: @VladTopala
Yes it was accidentally, sorry , corrected now ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you say you tried setting the text, but the setText method actually replaces the whole current text with the new one:

```
JTextComponent @1669:
((AbstractDocument)doc).replace(0, doc.getLength(), t,null);
```

You should use [insert](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#insert(java.lang.String,%20int)) or [append](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append(java.lang.String)) methods:

Replace

```
System.out.println(s);
```

with

```
textArea.append(s);
```

Also, check the following question for a better way of doing this:

> [Opening, Editing and Saving text in JTextArea to .txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24077092/1191034)

```
private void fileRead(){
    try{    
        FileReader read = new FileReader("filepath");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(read);
            while(scan.hasNextLine()){
            String temp = scan.nextLine() + System.lineSeparator();
            storeAllString = storeAllString + temp;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

@Hovercraft's suggestion is very good. If you don't want to process the file in any way, you could directly read it into the JTextArea:

```
try {
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    textArea.read(br, "Stream description");
} catch (IOException e2) {
    e2.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaank you so much, this works for me :)

Comment: Better to read directly into the JTextArea using its `read(...)` method and a BufferedReader.